# Discord.js - How do I remove all messages sent by a bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I only want my bot to have a single message, so each time it sends a message, its previous message is deleted. What I'm trying to do is loop through all the messages and see if the ID matches the bot. Here is the command:

```
if(message.content.startsWith(`${PREFIX}update`)){
    const channel = message.channel
    const messages = await channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 100 });
    messages.forEach(msg => **IF MESSAGE IS SENT BY BOT, DELETE IT**); 
    message.channel.send("update");
}
```

How do I see if the message is sent by the bot and delete it? I've only seen people deleting a certain number of messages before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) has a property called [bot](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=bot) which will be true/false depending on if the account is a bot or not. You can use that to check if the message you want to delete was sent by a bot.

Moreover, you can use [message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message).[author](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User).[id](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/Snowflake) to check the ID of the author. (Just in case you want to delete messages by a certain bot.)

Examples:

```js
    if (message.content.startsWith(`${PREFIX}update`)) {
        const Channel = message.channel;
        const Messages = await Channel.messages.fetch({limit: 100});

        Messages.forEach(msg => { // Checking if the message author has a certain ID.
            if (msg.author.id == "ID") msg.delete()
        });

        message.channel.send("Updated");
    };
});
```

```js
    if (message.content.startsWith(`${PREFIX}update`)) {
        const Channel = message.channel;
        const Messages = await Channel.messages.fetch({limit: 100});

        Messages.forEach(msg => { // Checking if the message author is a bot.
            if (msg.author.bot) msg.delete()
            // This will delete messages from any bot.
        });

        message.channel.send("Updated");
    };
```

Deleting a message by ID:

```js
const Channel = client.channels.cache.get("ChannelID");
Channel.messages.fetch("MessageID").then(message => message.delete())
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I also have another question. How do I delete a message based on the message's id? ex. delete message with id of "MESSAGE_ID"

Comment: @DeviousDev I've updated my answer according to your comment.

Comment: @Jayke Thank you so much! Your answer was so helpful!